# How to set dynamic height of custom UITabelview cell in swit

Tags: iphone, uitableview, row-height

I have a UITableView that is populated with custom cells which had created by Xib(autolayout).The cell consist of multiple labels  images etc and size of size of changes according to response we get from api.I have been trying hard set height dynamically. I am using following methods.

```
func createTabelView ()
    {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "DBEventCell", bundle: nil)
        self.eventTabelVew.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: Constants.CELL_IDENTIFIER)

        self.eventTabelVew.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        self.eventTabelVew.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.eventTabelVew.separatorStyle = .None //UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
        self.eventTabelVew.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor();
        self.eventTabelVew.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();

        self.eventTabelVew.setNeedsLayout()
        self.eventTabelVew.layoutIfNeeded()
    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
     {
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
func tableView(tleView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

but this not working.Please do help as I am struck last from last few days.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need this function

```
 func tableView(tleView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

also you should check your cell autolayout constrains and adjusting properties of UI components to make it contract or expand with content also check this tutorial

https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: IF remove this function  estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath  still the problem remains same,I also followed the tutorials on "https://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/"  but it did not worked